# C Splitting up a char string that contains an integer

Tags: c, string

I am trying to split up a string into 3 variables of type int,char,int. I have the following string to split 1000P3. I have the following code to do this but the char variable is containg the P3 instead of just the P.

```
int num1;
char type [10];
int num2 =0;
sscanf("1000P3","%d %c %d",&num1,type,&num2);
```

Any assistance would be grateful.

Comment: why do you use `&` before num1/num2, but not before `type`?

Comment: Can you please explain the desired result?
The program is giving following output on my system:-
`user@ubuntu:/tmp$ ./a.out 
num1=1000
type=P
num2=3
user@ubuntu:/tmp$ `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%c` reads a single character, not a character string. That you saw 3 was just a coincidence from undefined behaviour. Try

```
int num1;
char type;
int num2;
sscanf("1000P3","%d %c %d", &num1, &type, &num2);
```

And remember to printf the character also with `%c`.

---

Also you should check the return value of `sscanf`; if it is not 3 (as we wanted to parse 3 items), then your input is incorrect.

Comment: That worked great, I had being messing about with different variants of regex to try and get it to read in correctly, cheers for the help, simple fixes are the best!

Answer (score 2):

An array of char that is null terminated is a string, and its name happens to be a pointer to an address already. 
so you can just use:

```
char type[10];
```

you would use:

```
sscanf("1000P3","%d %s %d",&num1,type,&num2);
                     ^           ^
```

A single char is treated just as you would an int.  To read its value, pass the *address of* the variable using the `&` operator.
So with

```
char type;
```

you would use:

```
sscanf("1000P3","%d %c %d",&num1,&type,&num2);
                     ^           ^
```